# Monitoring GC in java

Tags: java, eclipse, command-line, garbage-collection, libgdx

Can someone explain to me how to monitor the garbace collector (GC) in Java as if I'm five years old?

Everything I read about it says to use the command line, but I don't really understand where, when or how to do that. I understand how to get the command window up, but I'm using Eclipse, and they don't really connect.

So when I see this:

```
-verbose:gc -XX:+PrintGCTimeStamps
```

Since I am not running my compiler from the command line: how would I use this in Eclipse? Every resource I reach from Google assumes I know how to use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is really no such thing as the garbage collector when you are invoking the compiler.

Assuming you are asking about how to set these options when you *execute* your application within Eclipse, then you want to add these as VM arguments in the Run dialog, [as in the highlighted text in this screenshot](http://wiki.eclipse.org/images/6/65/UML2Tools_Run_Eclipse_Application_VM_Parameters.JPG).

Comment: thank you simple enough i was really close i was just adding -java to the beginning which gave an error so i thought i was wrong. the screen shot cleared it up thank you.

Comment: If you are interested in some other ways of monitoring the GC you can download the Visual GC Plugin for the VisualVM